# Installing the latest Docker version on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, software-installation, docker

When I follow the [official instructions](http://docs.docker.io/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-trusty-1404-lts-64-bit) for Ubuntu 14.04, I end up with docker `0.9.1`. When I do it for Ubuntu 12.04 it correctly installs the latest version: `0.11`.

How can I install `0.11` on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: The 14.04 installation is pulling the binary from the 14.04 repos, they only have version 0.9.1. If you want 0.11 you need to pull it from the docker repos, like the 12.04 instructions tell you to.

Comment: ... similar or the same question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/472412/how-do-i-upgrade-docker

Comment: Or you can follow the hacker installation: http://docs.docker.io/installation/binaries/

Comment: The reason you can't find good instructions is that this isn't really supported. If it was possible to do reliably, there would be a passage about it in the Docker installation instructions; but they say you need at least Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/

Upgrade Docker

To install the latest version of Docker with apt-get:

$ apt-get upgrade docker-engine

Comment: This doesn't work at all. The issue is that the latest version from the 14.04 repo is .9.1. The issue is _not_ how to upgrade it.