# How to fix missing gpg key even though it should have been imported?

Tags: apt, ppa, gnupg, docker

I am changing the way I install docker on a bunch of machines [as pointed out here](https://askubuntu.com/a/473720/32792). It worked fine on one, yet this one behaves strangely.

I have imported the key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.uUGtmucAUd --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/atareao-telegram.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/neovim-ppa-unstable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nilarimogard-webupd8.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ondrej-php-7_0.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/shutter-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/vincent-c-ponysay.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xorg-edgers-ppa.gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
gpg: requesting key 2C52609D from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key 2C52609D: public key "Docker Release Tool (releasedocker) <docker@docker.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

yet still `sudo apt-get update` fails on missing key:

```
w: GPG error: https://apt.dockerproject.org ubuntu-trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F76221572C52609D
```

What am I missing?

I also tried the currently provided answer, yet after deleting the trusted.gpg file, I cannot add the keys with

```
root@fluttershy:/etc/apt# rm trusted.gpg
root@fluttershy:/etc/apt# apt-key update
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key 437D05B5: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key FBB75451: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key C0B21F32: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof
gpg: key EFE21092: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg:               imported: 4  (RSA: 2)
root@fluttershy:/etc/apt#
```

Comment: gpg is failing with `invalid packet (ctb=01)`/`keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof`. This usually means that your GPG database is damaged. The quickest way to fix the issue is to delete it. Is it an option?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini It depends on what is deleted and needs to be reconfigured. It's an option to delete all public keys of vendors, I would like to keep my own private and public keys. Such an answer would be even more great if it shows a way on how to list the currently imported keys; as I have a few PPAs  I want to keep on using.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini And amazing how selective I was reading the output of the `apt-key` command. I was only scanning the last line and assumed it worked /o'\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gpg is failing with `invalid packet (ctb=01)`/`keydb_get_keyblock failed: eof`. This usually means that your GPG keyring is damaged. The quickest way to fix the issue is to delete it, or restore it from a backup.

Here are a few handy commands for you:

- To list all keys currently in APT keyrings:

  ```
  apt-key list
  ```
- To restore `trusted.gpg` from APT automatic backup:

  ```
  cp /etc/apt/trusted.gpg{~,}
  ```
- To delete `trusted.gpg` and re-create it with the keys for the Ubuntu archive:

  ```
  rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
  apt-key update
  ```

In all the commands I have used `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`, but beware that there may be other keyrings inside `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`.

APT uses all the keyrings at the same time, as you can see by examining your output:

```
Executing: gpg [...] \
  --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg \
  --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg \
  --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/atareao-telegram.gpg \
  --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/neovim-ppa-unstable.gpg \
  --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nilarimogard-webupd8.gpg \
  [...]
```

Having one damaged keyring makes GPG sad and none of the keyrings (even the good ones) are trusted. As a result, none of the keys considered.

Comment: Even after deleting the trusted.gpg file, it still throws the same error

Comment: @k0pernikus: can you paste the exact commands you used, together with the output from `apt-key list`?

Comment: It fails on the apt-key update part. See my question, I have added the part.

Comment: @k0pernikus: `trusted.gpg` is not the only keyring available. There are others inside `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`, and it appears that the problem is with one of them. You should use the output of `apt-key list` to detect the damaged one

Comment: The last part was the key: I moved all the gpg keys out of the folders. Then apt-get update kindly listed all the missing keys and I just needed to add them according to the list.

Comment: Which of the keys was faulty I do not know. It would be kind if you could elaborate why one key might crash the whole keyring.

Comment: @k0pernikus: updated answer

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Is the faulty gpg file below or above the `gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=01)
gpg: keydb_search_next failed: invalid packet` error ?

Answer (score 4):

Specifically, for Docker keyring `58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D` add key server:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
```